# Mintty window brought to forefront causes keyboard backlight to turn off

Tags: msys2, mintty

With a fresh install of

- git version 2.37.0.windows.1

which has

- mintty version 3.6.1 (x86_64-pc-msys)[Windows 19043]

The **keyboard back-light turns off** whenever the mintty window is brought to the forefront.  When I push the back-light toggle button on the keyboard the light flashes on for a fraction of a second, then off. I want the keyboard back-light to always be on. When another window is brought to the forefront the back-light turns on.  When the mintty window is exited the back-light turns on. No other applications have this feature.

Under the mintty options drop down menu, there seem to be no settings for this feature.

In web searches Xset is referenced, however it looks like that is not available by default with mintty.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late but this link helped me https://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg169125.html

Basically, you just have to add ManageLEDs=3 to your .minttyrc

In my case it is located in C:\msys64\home<user>

I tested and it also works on Git Bash and Cygwin

Hope that helps!